# Google Cloud Functions enable CORS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-functions

I just finished the Hello World Google Cloud Functions tutorial and received the following response headers:

```
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 14
Content-Type → text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date → Mon, 29 Feb 2016 07:02:37 GMT
Execution-Id → XbT-WC9lXKL-0
Server → nginx
```

How can I add the CORS headers to be able to call my function from my website?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

here we go:

```
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {  
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // stop preflight requests here
    res.status(204).send('');
    return;
  }

  // handle full requests
  res.status(200).send('weeee!);
};
```

then you can jquery/whatever it as usual:

```
$.get(myUrl, (r) => console.log(r))
```

Comment: i've tried the above implementation but I receive:Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. any suggestion?

Comment: try adding res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content Type', 'X-Requested-Width', '...') before sending the response

Comment: ```It does not have HTTP ok status.```

Comment: How to do same in python runtime?

Comment: @bikram https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests

Comment: I could only make this work after setting the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Origin explicitly also on the main response.

Answer (score 34):

I'm the product manager for Google Cloud Functions. Thanks for your question, this has been a popular request.

We don't have anything to announce just yet, but we're aware of several enhancements that need to be made to the HTTP invocation capabilities of Cloud Functions and we'll be rolling out improvements to this and many other areas in future iterations.

UPDATE:

We've improved the way you deal with HTTP in Cloud Functions.  You now have full access to the HTTP Request/Response objects so you can set the appropriate CORS headers and respond to pre-flight OPTIONS requests (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http)

**UPDATE (2022):**

Just noticed there was a question about docs, and our docs have moved. Updated docs for CORS are here:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors

Comment: The link provided (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) doesn't mention anything about cors. Is there any official documentation to look at? I was hoping there would be a UI to change these settings (a la aws) but there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Is CORS supported in the beta python environment?

Comment: The Python environment uses Flask as its web framework, so you should be able to manually set CORS headers using standard Flask semantics. We're gradually adding python samples where they're missing, and this is one of them. Setting headers in Flask discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464276/add-response-headers-to-flask-web-app

Comment: documentation here is quite confusing. 
 ttps://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events . How is it related to express?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the CORS express middleware.

**package.json**

```
npm install express --save
npm install cors --save
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();

app.use(cors);
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Hello, world`);
});

exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just created [webfunc](https://github.com/nicolasdao/webfunc). It's a lightweight HTTP server that supports CORS as well as routing for Google Cloud Functions. Example:

```
const { serveHttp, app } = require('webfunc')

exports.yourapp = serveHttp([
  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send('Hello World')),
  app.get('/users/{userId}', (req, res, params) => res.status(200).send(`Hello user ${params.userId}`)),
  app.get('/users/{userId}/document/{docName}', (req, res, params) => res.status(200).send(`Hello user ${params.userId}. I like your document ${params.docName}`)),
])
```

In your project's root, simply add a ***appconfig.json*** that looks like this:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "1296000"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

In the python environment, you can use the [flask request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request) to manage CORS requests.

```
def cors_enabled_function(request):
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    return ('Hello World!', 200, headers)
```

See the [gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) for more.

Answer (score 4):

You need to send an `'OPTIONS'` response by setting its header as follows:

```js
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  res.status(204).send('');
}
```

Runtime: NodeJS 10

Comment: This is a preflight request handler. See [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#functions_http_cors-nodejs) for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If you tried the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418322/6243352) but encountered a preflight error, the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#preflight_request) offer examples of handling it in multiple languages, with the [caveat](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#cors-limitations) that it only works on public functions, i.e. deployed with `--allow-unauthenticated`:

```js
exports.corsEnabledFunction = (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    /* handle preflight OPTIONS request */
    
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

    // cache preflight response for 3600 sec
    res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    
    return res.sendStatus(204);
  }

  // handle the main request
  res.send("main response");
};
```

Another option is to use Express as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66465939/6243352), complete with cross-origin enabled.

Comment: Note: 6 months after the original answer: the accepted answer has been edited to handle CORS, but I'll leave this up for posterity because it seems clearer.

Comment: This should be higher up, I haven't seen this troublesome caveat mentioned anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You must enable CORS within all your functions, for example hello function:

**index.js**

```
const cors = require('cors')();

// My Hello Function
function hello(req, res) {
  res.status(200)
    .send('Hello, Functions');
};

// CORS and Cloud Functions export
exports.hello = (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    hello(req, res);
  });
}
```

Don't forget about package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "function-hello",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After applying your favourite answer from here, if you're still getting this error, check for uncaught errors in your cloud function. This can result in the browser receiving a CORS error, even when your error has nothing to do with CORS

Answer (score 0):

After CORS enabled if you send POST request to your function also check for your request Content-Type header, mine was set it to "text/plain" and my browser was constantly triggering CORS errors, after setting the header to "application/json" everything worked properly.