# Unable to add cors to gcp function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to enable cors for a google cloud function. My index.js is:

```
const cors = require('cors');

exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {
  if (req.body.message === undefined) {
    console.log('No message defined!');
  } else {
    console.log(req.body.message);    
  }

//res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
//res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

  cors(req, res, () => {
        console.log('inside cors');
        res.status(200).send(users);
    });
  //cors(res.status(200).send(users));

//res.status(200).send(users);
  //res.end();
};
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "2.8.4"
    }
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693758/google-cloud-functions-enable-cors/36076295) link I tried to add the headers manually but with no success. I've also tried [this](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/05/enabling-cors-middleware-firebase-cloud-functions/) solution but with no prevail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the following headers:

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
```

The solution form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693758/google-cloud-functions-enable-cors/36076295) thread was not enough for me. I still received errors: `Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

By adding the line `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');` it worked.