# How can I have multiple API endpoints for one Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

I have a Google Cloud Function which contains multiple modules to be invoked on different paths.

I am using the serverless framework to deploy my functions, but it has the limitation of only one path per function.

I want to use multiple paths in one function just like we can in the AWS serverless framework.

Suppose a `user` cloud function will have two paths `/user/add` as well as `/user/remove`; both the paths should invoke the same function.

Something like this:

`serverless.yml`

```
functions:
  user:
    handler: handle
    events:
      - http: user/add
      - http: user/remove
```

How can I have multiple API endpoints for one GCF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed there is no actual REST service backing up Google Cloud Functions. It uses out of the box HTTP triggers.

To hustle the way around, I'm using my request payload to determine which action to perform. In the body, I'm adding a key named `"path"`.

For example, consider the Function USER.

To add a user:

```
{
  "path":"add",
  "body":{
    "first":"Jhon",
    "last":"Doe"
  }
}
```

To remove a user:

```
{
  "path":"remove",
  "body":{
    "first":"Jhon",
    "last":"Doe"
  }
}
```

If your operations are purely CRUD, you can use `request.method` which offers verbs like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` to determine operations.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Firebase Hosting to rewriting URLs.

In your **firebase.json** file:

```
"hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "/api/v1/your/path/here",
            "function": "your_path_here"
          }
    ]
}
```

Keep in mind this is a workaround and it has a major drawback: you will pay for double hit. Consider this if your app has to scale.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your functions in different [runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http). The `Node.js` runtime uses the `Express` framework. So you can use its router to build different routes within a single function.

Add the dependency

```
npm install express@4.17.1
```

The following example is using typescript. Follow these [guidelines](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/master/docs/typescript.md) to initiate a typescript project.

```js
// index.ts
import { HttpFunction } from '@google-cloud/functions-framework';
import * as express from 'express';

import foo from './foo';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use('/foo', foo)

const index: HttpFunction = (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from the index route...');
};
router.get('', index)
app.use('/*', router)

export const api = app
```

```js
// foo.ts
import { HttpFunction } from '@google-cloud/functions-framework';
import * as express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

const foo: HttpFunction = (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from the foo route...');
};

router.get('', foo)

export default router;
```

to deploy run:

```
gcloud functions deploy YOUR_NAME \
--runtime nodejs16 \
--trigger-http \
--entry-point api \
--allow-unauthenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in google allows only one event definition per function is supported. [For more](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/events/)

Answer (score 0):

Express can be installed with `npm i express`, then imported and used more or less as normal to handle routing:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// enable CORS if desired
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world");
});

exports.example = app; // `example` is whatever your GCF entrypoint is
```

---

If Express isn't an option for some reason or the use case is very simple, a custom router may suffice.

If parameters or wildcards are involved, consider using [`route-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/route-parser). A [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162369/6243352) suggested [this app](https://github.com/anishkny/realworld-gcp-datastore-cloud-functions/blob/master/src/Router.js) as an example.

The Express request object has a few useful parameters you can take advantage of:

- `req.method` which gives the HTTP verb
- `req.path` which gives the path without the query string
- `req.query` object of the parsed key-value query string
- `req.body` the parsed JSON body

Here's a simple proof-of-concept to illustrate:

```js
const routes = {
  GET: {
    "/": (req, res) => {
      const name = (req.query.name || "world");
      res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en"><body><h1>
          hello ${name.replace(/[\W\s]/g, "")}
        </h1></body></html>
      `);
    },
  },
  POST: {
    "/user/add": (req, res) => { // TODO stub
      res.json({
        message: "user added", 
        user: req.body.user
      });
    },
    "/user/remove": (req, res) => { // TODO stub
      res.json({message: "user removed"});
    },
  },
};

exports.example = (req, res) => {
  if (routes[req.method] && routes[req.method][req.path]) {
    return routes[req.method][req.path](req, res);
  }

  res.status(404).send({
    error: `${req.method}: '${req.path}' not found`
  });
};
```

Usage:

```bash
$ curl https://us-east1-foo-1234.cloudfunctions.net/example?name=bob
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en"><body><h1>
        hello bob
      </h1></body></html>
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"user": "bob"}' \
> https://us-east1-foo-1234.cloudfunctions.net/example/user/add
{"message":"user added","user":"bob"}
```

If you run into trouble with CORS and/or preflight issues, see [Google Cloud Functions enable CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693758/google-cloud-functions-enable-cors/66494563#66494563)