# Enable Cors in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-firestore, cors

I have written some cloud functions and deployed them now i am trying to hit those APIs using my Angular application but i am getting this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I know i have to enable cors in my cloud function but i have never done that before so would be awesome if you guys could tell me how to do that?
I did checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693758/google-cloud-functions-enable-cors/43418322) thread but i am a little bit confused as to where i need to initialize the cors and do i need to install its dependency too and where do i need to enable it in my cloud function? Here is my cloud function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

const usersCollection = db.collection("users");

exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.body.username != null && req.body.firstname != null && req.body.lastname != null && req.body.addr1 != null && req.body.addr2 != null || req.body.username != undefined && req.body.firstname != undefined && req.body.lastname != undefined && req.body.addr1 != undefined && req.body.addr2 != undefined ) {
        let docId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 00000));
        let newUser = {
            "username": req.body.name,
            "firstname": req.body.firstname,
            "lastname": req.body.lastname,
            "addr1": req.body.addr1,
            "addr2": req.body.addr2,
        }
        usersCollection.add(newUser).then(snapshot => {
            res.send(200, {
                "message": "User was successfully created"
            })
        });


    } else {
        res.send(400, {
            "message": "All fields are required"
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this

1. Using externally library to handle `OPTIONS` call

[cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

2. Handle `OPTIONS` call manually

Get request Method from `headers`

Check if the method is `OPTIONS`

Resolve the API with `200` status code.

```
 exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

 if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
   res.end();
}

else{
        if (req.body.username != null && req.body.firstname != null && req.body.lastname != null && req.body.addr1 != null && req.body.addr2 != null || req.body.username != undefined && req.body.firstname != undefined && req.body.lastname != undefined && req.body.addr1 != undefined && req.body.addr2 != undefined ) {
            let docId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 00000));
            let newUser = {
                "username": req.body.name,
                "firstname": req.body.firstname,
                "lastname": req.body.lastname,
                "addr1": req.body.addr1,
                "addr2": req.body.addr2,
            }
            usersCollection.add(newUser).then(snapshot => {
                res.send(200, {
                    "message": "User was successfully created"
                })
            });


        } else {
            res.send(400, {
                "message": "All fields are required"
            })
        }
}
    });
```

Comment: can you edit my cloud function because as i said i am not sure where do i need to edit my code

Comment: I've added portion of code into your cloud function. Once check and let me know if any error as I didn't tested it.

Comment: do we need to remove it when requests are sent from a production url ?

Comment: @DamienRomito browser will make `OPTIONS` call if your client app and server app running in the different domains. If you gonna host both client and server app in the same domain, then no need to handle `OPTIONS` call as browser itself won't make that call

Answer (score 0):

On server side try this:
`npm install cors`.
Then 
`const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});`
Maybe this link will help you: [Enabling CORS in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
Also you can disable CORS rules in browser using plugin, for example in crome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en