# CORS error on httpsCallable firebase in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions, create-react-app

SOLVED - See my answer below.

Callable function is causing CORS error like this:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://us-central1-careerhub-a50a2.cloudfunctions.net/createUser'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Function code:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const email = data.email
    const password = data.password

    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: password
    }).then((res) => {
        return {
            response: res
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        return {err}
    })

})
```

Client-side:

```
    const handleAddUser = () => {
      let pswd = passwordGen(7)
      const createUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createUser');
      createUser({email: email, password: pswd}).then(function(result) {
        let res = result.data
        console.log(res)
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.code)
      })

    }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "careerhub-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "antd": "^4.0.2",
    "firebase": "^7.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-email-editor": "^1.0.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "recharts": "^2.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This error persists even if I'm offline.

Things I've tried:

1. Updating firebase SDK
2. Adding "proxy" : '...' to package.json
3. Using basic functions from the cloud functions guides
4. Deleting firebase app and deleting function and redeploying
5. Adding `const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});` to function

Comment: You should add cors in your firebase function.
check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326098/enable-cors-in-firebase-cloud-function

Comment: @DavidAgustinMelgar forgot to add that I had tried this to no success. Tried again to be certain with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error turned out to be a poorly documented change on Google's end around IAM permissions, which are not clearly accessible via the Firebase console.

**The Cause:**

Cloud functions were forbidding access to the function. Newly created functions did not have a Cloud Functions Invoker. This change was implemented on Jan 15, 2020

**Solution:**

Create Cloud Functions Invoker and set to allUsers.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam

Comment: ALL DAY. I just spent all day trying to figure this out. Thank you for coming back and posting the solution. for anyone else that stumbles upon this add "allUsers" as a member of the function and select "Cloud Functions Invoker" as the role.

Comment: This worked for me but with permission set to allAuthenticatedUsers and role set to Cloud Functions Admin. Cloud functions Invoker wasn't enough. Is this correct?

Comment: this solution is for google not firebase interface. firebase interface does not have the option to change access to AllUsers

Comment: If you are using firebase interface, you should just add Cloud Functions Invoker role to adminsdk entity and don't forget to redeploy or manually delete functions from Cloud Functions and deploy again to apply changes in permissions