# Firebase https onCall function blocked by cors

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have a `sendMail` cloud function that I want to use to send emails from a contact form on my site. The site is hosted on Firebase with a custom Google domain. The issue is that I get this error whenever I try to invoke the function from the hosted site.

[image]

Here's what I have tried so far

1. I have tried testing the function locally from the browser and it works just fine. No cors error.
2. Testing by invoking the function from the firebase shell also works just fine without any cors error.

[image]

3. I have checked my Google Cloud console and made sure all users can invoke the function.
   [image]

4. I have also tried using the cors library to wrap the function but that hasn't worked either:

Here is how I am calling my `sendMail` function:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sendMail = firebase.app().functions('us-central1').httpsCallable("sendMail");
    
    sendMail({ details: this.state })
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: true,
        });
        this.notify("success");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.notify(error);
      });
  };
```

Here is the entire `sendMail` function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

admin.initializeApp();

// Use gmail to set up transporter
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: functions.config().mail.user,
    pass: functions.config().mail.pass
  },
});

exports.sendMail = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const info = data.details;
    const mailOptions = {
      from: `${info.name} <${info.email}>`,
      to: functions.config().mail.dest,
      subject: info.subject,
      html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">${info.name}, ${info.email}</p>
                    <p
                    style="
                        font-size: 1rem;
                        background: #FFECB3;
                        padding: 10px;
                        border-radius: 10px;">${info.message}</p>
                `, // email content in HTML
    };

    // returning results
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("failed", err);
      }
    });
  });
```

I know similar questions have been asked but I have really tried almost everything. I ONLY get the cors issue when invoking it from my firebase hosted site. Someone, please help!

Comment: Hi @JilloAbdullahi could you please check these two cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326098/enable-cors-in-firebase-cloud-function) and give it a try on their solutions? Some possible solutions and the correct way of declaring and using the `cors` library is showed there and I believe it might help you.

Comment: Hey @gso_gabriel. I actually came to realize that cors is automatically handled for onCall functions. The issue was that I had not run a build on the bit where I include the region when invoking the function. Just needed to run build and redeploy. All the headache for just that but it's all good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onCall functions behaviour differently than onRequest with regards to the cors, for example you need to ensure you're calling it from the same region. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278537/firebase-callable-function-cors)

The cors issue can occur if your function is erroring, worth checking in the emmulator & your send mail response.

Comment: It was indeed an issue with not specifying the region when calling the function since I had included it in the definition. Just fixed this and it's all good. Thanks.