# Is there any way to get rid of CORS in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am facing the CORS error for a cloud function I recently deployed even though I have included `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in my code:

```golang
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    "cloud.google.com/go/logging"
    "github.com/Task3/models"
    "github.com/Task3/validations"
)

func CreateEmployee(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    var employee models.Employee
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&employee)

    if err != nil {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        http.Error(w, "Invalid JSON", http.StatusBadRequest)

        logger.Log(logging.Entry{
            Payload:  "Invalid JSON input for type Employee during controllers.CreateEmployee function call.",
            Severity: logging.Error,
        })
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        return
    }

    err1 := validations.V.Struct(employee)

    if err1 != nil {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        http.Error(w, "Invalid input for employee deatails\n-First name must contain alphabets or spaces only.\n-First name must contain alphabets or spaces only.\n-Email id must be valid eg. abc@example.com.\n-Password must be atleast 6 charecters long.\n-Phone no. should be valid.\n-Role must be either of - 'admin', 'developer', 'manager', 'tester'. (case sensetive)\n-Salary must be a number.\n-Birthdate should be in yyyy-mm-dd format.", http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)

        logger.Log(logging.Entry{
            Payload:  fmt.Sprintf("Invalid employee data input : occured while validating employee fields during controllers.CreateEmployee function call.\n%v", err1),
            Severity: logging.Error,
        })

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        return
    }

    // Query to get the maximum employee ID
    iter := client.Collection("ems").OrderBy("ID", firestore.Desc).Limit(1).Documents(ctx)

    var lastEmployee models.Employee

    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        doc.DataTo(&lastEmployee)
        // break
    }

    // Generate new employee ID
    EmpId := lastEmployee.ID + 1
    employee.ID = EmpId

    // Save employee data to Firestore
    _, _, err = client.Collection("ems").Add(ctx, employee)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Log(logging.Entry{
            Payload:  "Failed to create employee",
            Severity: logging.Error,
        })
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        http.Error(w, "Failed to create employee", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Setting headers and staus codes
    // Set CORS headers for all requests
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

    // Handle preflight request
    if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(employee)

    logger.Log(logging.Entry{
        Payload:  fmt.Sprintf("Employee created successfully with emp id %v", EmpId),
        Severity: logging.Info,
    })

}
```

It works in Postman but not on other clients than Postman.

I deployed my cloud function by adding appropriate headers for CORS but it still give me a CORS failure error whenever I try to invoke my function.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#cors) about this? You did something very different than what is suggested.

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation to understand what CORS is and what it is not. CORS is a web browser feature. An HTTP request in Postman will work and then fail in the browser because Postman does not validate cross-origin requests. Once you understand what CORS is, you will have an easier time responding to the various HTTP methods with the correct origin headers.

Comment: What is "the CORS error"? Add the precise error message you observe in your question. Also, setting the CORS response header should be the first thing your handler does. Given the current state of your code, CORS-preflight requests cannot be successful.

Answer (score 2):

Despite what the GCF documentation tells you, manual implementation of CORS is rarely a good idea, as it's quite error-prone. Case in point: [Google Cloud's Go example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#cors) misclassifies all `OPTIONS` requests as CORS-preflight requests; more about this topic in [one of my blog posts](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly).

Instead, you're almost always better off relying on a CORS middleware library. For instance, here is a proof of concept of a 1st-gen Go-based Google Cloud Function configured for CORS with my own library, [jub0bs/cors](https://github.com/jub0bs/cors):

```golang
package p

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/jub0bs/cors"
)

var Handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)

func init() {
    corsMw, err := cors.NewMiddleware(cors.Config{
        Origins:        []string{"*"},
        Methods:        []string{http.MethodPost},
        RequestHeaders: []string{"Content-Type"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    Handler = corsMw.Wrap(http.HandlerFunc(HelloWorld)).ServeHTTP
}

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World!")
}
```

And here is an equivalent proof of concept of a 2nd-gen GCF:

```golang
package helloworld

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/functions"
  "github.com/jub0bs/cors"
)

func init() {
    corsMw, err := cors.NewMiddleware(cors.Config{
        Origins:        []string{"*"},
        Methods:        []string{http.MethodPost},
        RequestHeaders: []string{"Content-Type"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    handler := corsMw.Wrap(http.HandlerFunc(HelloWorld)).ServeHTTP
    functions.HTTP("HelloHTTP", handler)
}

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World!")
}
```

---

Of course, whether you opt for a 1st-gen or a 2nd-gen GCF, you will also need to adequately populate the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files.