# My Web app is being blocked by CORS policy even after installing CORS in my Express app

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have a  flutter web app that I am running on localhost to debug, my web app posts data to my Firebase Cloud functions API which then sends data to Google Bigquery to create a table, although I have installed CORS already I keep getting this error in my browser below

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-denance-cbf3f.cloudfunctions.net/api/create_table' from origin 'http://localhost:55073' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    us-central1-denance-cbf3f.cloudfunctions.net/api/create_table:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
    errors.dart:202 Uncaught (in promise) Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
        C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 897:28                get current
    packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 71:22                                                                                    <fn>
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18                                        handleValue
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:44                                        handleValueCallback
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 736:13                                        _propagateToListeners
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 533:7                                         [_complete]
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1219:7                                             <fn>
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37324:58                              <fn>
    
    
        at Object.createErrorWithStack (:55073/dart_sdk.js:5070)
        at Object._rethrow (:55073/dart_sdk.js:37715)
        at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (:55073/dart_sdk.js:37711)
        at Object._microtaskLoop (:55073/dart_sdk.js:37568)
        at _startMicrotaskLoop (:55073/dart_sdk.js:37574)
        at :55073/dart_sdk.js:33324
```

this is my code below

const functions = require("firebase-functions");

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const bigquery = new BigQuery();
var app = express();
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);


app.post('/create_table', cors(dynamicCorsOptions), function (req, res,) {


  'use strict';


  async function createTable() {


    let schema = [];


    async function groupUp() {

      for (let key in req.body) {


        schema.push({ name: req.body[key]['name'], type: req.body[key]['type'] });


      }


    }

    await groupUp();


    await doingIt();


    async function doingIt() {


      var datasetId = 'denanse'; // Existing dataset
      var tableId = 'hrhrhhh'; // Table to be created

      const options = {
        schema: schema,
        location: 'US',
      };

      const [table] = await bigquery
        .dataset(datasetId)
        .createTable(tableId, options);

      console.log(`Table ${table.id} created.`);
      res.send(`Table ${table.id} created.`);

    }

  }

  createTable();


});
```

how can I resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35693758/109941

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Functions enable CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693758/google-cloud-functions-enable-cors)

Answer (score -1):

Currently your usage of the `cors` package is bugged in two ways. You only need to implement either of the below fixes.

#### Enable CORS on all routes

Because you've imported and used the `cors` package like so:

```js
var cors = require('cors');
// ...
app.use(cors);
```

You've attached the `cors` constructor to the Express application rather than an instance of the `cors` middleware (You are calling `cors(options)` with `cors(request)`). The options object and its properties are covered in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options).

In its most basic form, you can use no configuration to allow CORS on **all** requests:

```js
app.use(cors())
```

However, this is *effectively* the same as just manually setting the CORS headers yourself to `*` along with [some other headers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options).

This is unsecure and goes against the point of CORS. You should instead configure it so that you only accept a handful of origins related to your project.

```js
/** The current project's ID */
export const PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;

/** Array of permitted origins for CORS */
export const CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
  "https://my.custom.domain",                // 0+ custom domains related to your project
  `https://${PROJECT_ID}.firebaseapp.com`,   // legacy Firebase Hosting domain
  `https://${PROJECT_ID}.web.app`,           // modern Firebase Hosting domain
  ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? []
    : ["localhost", "undefined"]             // permit CORS on localhost, only while emulated
  ),
];

app.use(cors({ origin: CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS }))
```

#### Enable CORS only on `/create_table`

Similar to above, you've attached the `cors()` middleware to the `/create_table` route using:

```js
app.post('/create_table', cors(dynamicCorsOptions), function (req, res) { /* ... */ });
```

Here, `dynamicCorsOptions` is `undefined` (at least in the code you've shared) which will use the CORS middleware on requests to `POST /create_table`. However, you need to handle `OPTIONS /create_table` too.

```js
// handle preflight requests
app.options('/create_table', cors(dynamicCorsOptions));

// handle actual requests
app.post('/create_table', cors(dynamicCorsOptions), function (req, res) { /* ... */ });
```

You can even use `cors({ origin: CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS })` from the above section for this.

#### Other points

- The [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/35dfe972ad0631857c23ae08b5c22786a3f78192/src/server.ts#L89-L95) (that runs your function), as [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request), parses the body of the request for you if it is set with the appropriate headers. This means you don't need `app.use(express.json())`.
- Your code calls `createTable()` but doesn't handle if it fails which will throw an unhandled Promise exception and terminate your function. You can either handle this case using `catch()` or the `try`/`catch` block in the next snippet:

```js
createTable()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to create table: " + err.code || err.message, err);
    res.status(500)
      .send("Failed to create table with unknown error");
  });
```

- Currently the execution of your `/create_table` handler jumps around quite a bit, I propose rearranging it for readability:

```js
app.post('/create_table', cors(dynamicCorsOptions), function (req, res) {
  'use strict';

  // this could be moved outside of the handler
  async function groupUp(requestBody) {
    const groups = [];
 
    for (let key in requestBody) {
      const { name, type } = requestBody[key];
      groups.push({ name, type });
    }

    return groups;
  }

  // this could be moved outside of the handler
  async function createTableInDataset(datasetId, schema) {
    const tableId = /* generate table ID */;

    const [table] = await bigquery
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .createTable(tableId, {
        schema,
        location: 'US',
      });

    return table.id;
  }

  async function createTable() {
    try {
      const schema = await groupUp(req.body);

      const createdTableId = createTableInDataset('denanse', schema);

      console.log(`Table ${createdTableId} created.`);
      res.status(201)
        .send(`Table ${createdTableId} created.`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to create table: " + err.code || err.message, err);
      res.status(500)
        .send("Failed to create table with unknown error");
    }
  }

  createTable();
});
```

Comment: @JimG. Spamming that comment on every question/answer is not helpful. Use the "close -> mark as duplicate" for that. While your linked question applies for general GCF functions (and until I edited the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418322/3068190) had a significant bug), the Firebase fork of CGF allows for finer controls over CORS behaviour as covered here. Understanding the problem is better than just pointing at an answer.